Solving for matrix in Ax=y
What can be said about the equation $Ax=y$ where $x,y$ are known vectors? I couldn't find much information about this equation online.
The problem where $A,x$ are known is trivial by simply multiplying $A$ and $x$ to get $y$.
The problem where $A,y$ are known is famous.
In particular, doing the least squares solution for $A$ in the first equation, I needed to invert the outer product of a vector which is impossible since it's rank-1. I understand that the solution set for $A$ of $Ax=y$ where $x,y$ are known is infinite. I understand that there is likely no neat structure (considering the geometry of linear transformations). But I wonder whether there are some interesting particular solutions for $A$.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Take any $x$ and define $y$ to be $Ax$ to get a  solution.

you have more unknowns than equatioms. The system is underdetermined, look it up.

In that case, perhaps the question is under what circumstances there is a unique solution for matrix A and if there is not a unique solution, is there at least some form of solution? If you treat this as a system of simultaneous equations, yes, it has already been solved (or proven to be unsolvable) but there may be interesting special cases.

$A = yx^T/|x|^2$

What do you mean when you say "there is likely no neat structure" ? Given that $Ax = y$ is an inhomogeneous linear equation (with respect to $A$), its solution space is a $n(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace of square matrices.
